# Android: ProgressDialog вызывается после HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

Делаю такую вещь как регистрация. Посылаю запрос на сервак через HttpURLConnection.

Функцию регистрации вызываю из RegisterActivity.java

```
ConnectionToServer toServer = new ConnectionToServer();
responseRegister = toServer.register(email, context);
```

Функции запросов к серваку в отдельной файле ConnectionToServer.java

```
public JSONObject register(String email, Context context) throws JSONException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    requestServer rS = new requestServer(context);
    rS.execute("http://myhost.com/registration?email=" + email);
    System.out.println(rS.get());
    return rS.get();
}

class requestServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{

    private Context mContext;
    public requestServer (Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        tools._progressDialog(mContext, "Ждите...", "Подождите, операция выполняется");
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strUrl) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        JSONObject json = null;
        try
        {
            // Send data
            URL url = new URL(strUrl[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); // здесь происходит исключение

            // Receive answer
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            wr.close();
            rd.close();

            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tools._progressDialogDismiss();
        }
        finally {
            assert conn != null;
            conn.disconnect();
        }

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        tools._progressDialogDismiss();
    }
}
```

ProgressDialog вызываю через Tools.java

```
public void _progressDialog(Context context, String title, String message){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle(title);
    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
    System.out.println("show");
}

public void _progressDialogDismiss(){
    if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("dismiss");
    }
}
```

Такой процесс: Ввожу мыло, нажимаю Submit. По идее должен сразу запуститься показ ProgressDialog. Но он запускается уже после того как запрос отправился и пришёл результат. То есть его вообще не показывается, так как он сразу и закрывается.

Помогите разобраться как правильно вызвать его сразу после нажатия Submit, а потом уже и запрос шёл.

**Добавленный код!**

mContext - тяну из RegisterActivity при вызове toServer.register(email, this);

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        tools._progressDialogDismiss();

        switch (doFunc){
            case "register":
                RegisterActivity rA = new RegisterActivity();
                try {
                    rA.doAfterRegister(jsonObject, mContext);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Ну и сама функция в RegisterActivity

```
public void doAfterRegister(JSONObject response, Context mContext) throws JSONException {
    if(Objects.equals(response.getString("code"), "200")){
        String message = response.getString("message");

        Tools._toastString(message, mContext);
        goToMainActivity(mContext);
    } else {
        String message = response.getString("message");

        Tools._toastString(message, mContext);
    }
}

public void goToMainActivity(Context mContext){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    System.out.println(intent);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Фалит на startActivity(intent);

```
27269-27269/com.ergonized.citylike_native E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ergonized.citylike_native, PID: 27269
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
```

**Спасибо за оказанную помощь!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы вызвав метод `get()` у `AsyncTask`. Мы вызываем метод `get`, чтобы получить результат работы `AsyncTask`. Но что будет, если задача еще не завершена, а мы вызвали `get`? Метод `get` будет ждать. Т.е. просто блокирует поток, в котором он выполняется, и не отпустит, пока не получит какой-то результат или не выскочит *exception*.

Вот и у вас поток заблокирован и не может показать диалог. Выполняйте ваши действия в `onPostExecute`. Там вы можете и убрать диалог, и выполнить переход в другое активити и тд.
Уберите:

```
System.out.println(rS.get());
return rS.get();
```

Comment: Получилось как Вы сказали. Теперь вот загвоздка в том, что в onPostExecute() я вызываю функцию из RegisterActivity.java, в ней проверяю результаты и потом вызываю другую функцию, которая показывает другой Активити на экране. Но дело в том, что когда я эту функцию вызываю просто при нажатии кнопки (ну типа "Назад"), то оно нормально переходит на Активити, а когда вызываю эту функцию onPostExecute(), то почему-то ругается на Intent. Добавлю код в шапку

Comment: @ЕвгенийСорокин, я полагаю, что дело в mContext, который вы используете и в последствии передаете в конструктор Intent'a. Так вот этим Context'ом должна выступать активити, что бы запустить новое активити. Измените: toServer.register(email, context); на toServer.register(email, RegisterActivity.this);

Comment: А так же возможно проблема в System.out.println(intent); т.к. я не уверен, что там корректно отрабатывает toString(). Так что советую закоментировать ту строчку и попробовать, это покажет наверняка

Comment: Не помогло(( Хотя я вот смотрю в логах Intent, одинаковый что при клике на кнопку Назад, что через Регистрацию. Но ни так ни так не работает...

Comment: У вас Intent разный скорее всего, одинаковые PackageName, которые вам выводит в лог. Так вы контекстом дали активити и закоментировали строку и не помогло?

Comment: Да, в функцию дал RegisterActivity.this, и убрал System.out.println(intent); Всё равно таже ошибка. Но я так понимаю если бы ошибка была в Context, то оно бы и Intent не создало. А так оно его создаёт, но не может запустить.